Problem connecting sqlite3 and php on linux
I have Apache web server installed on Manjaro(Sway) linux, and default location of projects is:
/srv/http/
I have created a folder for my project by the name test in the location and have created a database named db1.db inside it through terminal using the following steps (followed this article):
sqlite3 db1

sqlite> create table tblone(one varchar(10), two smallint);

sqlite> insert into tblone values('helloworld',20);
sqlite> insert into tblone values('linux', 30);

I can verify that the table has been created successfully by running the following command:
sqlite> select * from tblone;

which outputs:
helloworld|20
linux|30

I need to create a PHP file which connects the above created database using PDO.
So, inside test folder, I create a file index.php with the following content:
<?php
    $myPDO = new PDO('sqlite:test/db1.db');
    $result = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM tblone");
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo $row['one']. "\n";
    }
?>

But I get a blank white screen in output, when I enter http://localhost/test/index.php in browser. Where am I going wrong?

Check your web server log files, you're likely getting a fatal error. The path to the db file is relative to the PHP file, so you probably just want 'sqlite:db1.db'.

@AlexHowansky, thanks for the comment. I tried setting the path to db1.db only, but that didn't help. The web server log file states this: [Wed Oct 09 01:11:57.508603 2024] [php:error] [pid 4497:tid 4497] [client ::1:42034] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /srv/http/test/index.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 /srv/http/test/index.php(2): PDO->__construct()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /srv/http/test/index.php on line 2 . But I am not able to understand it? What should I do? Can you help?

"could not find driver" means that your PHP installation does not include the required module to support SQLite. If you do php -m from the command line, you'll get a list of installed modules, which should include pdo_sqlite but probably doesn't. Not familiar at all with Manjaro/Sway so can't help in regards to how you'd install that. It might be as simple as uncommenting (or adding) the line extension=pdo_sqlite.so in your php.ini file.

@AlexHowansky, just checked and I see that I haved pdo_sqlite installed, Have uncommented the pdo_sqlite in the php.ini file as well. Now I am getting the following message in the log: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file ...

"unable to open database file" means either the file isn't where you're telling it, or permissions aren't correct. Try using the full path like new PDO('sqlite:/srv/http/test/db1.db') (or whatever it is) and maybe chmod go+r it if needed.

Also note, your db file should never be under the document root, or a visitor could just request http://localhost/test/db1.db and grab your entire raw database.

@AlexHowansky, I did some debugging searching from google, and got an error General error: 1 no such table: tblone in /srv/http/test/index.php. But its working fine now. This had something to do with write permissions at project folder. Plus, I had to use either private or protected for a database. When I did that, it's working now. And I created the database once again. Thanks!
